# Google cloud is throwing the error saying updating service failed when I try to run mvn appengine:deploy

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

Google cloud is throwing the error saying updating service failed when I try to run mvn appengine:deploy

The error log looks like this.

GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] The App Engine service account does not exist for

How can this be resolved?